# How to get Gaussian distribution quantile in c++

Tags: c++, distribution, normal-distribution, quantile

What is the C++ equivalent of python's `stats.norm.ppf(probability)`? Are there built-in c++ functions for it, or can you call python functions from C++?

Is boost the only way to do it? but I am trouble installing boost.

Comment: Side note: Installing boost is dead easy if your development system has a decent package manager. If you have to download , configure, and compile boost on your own, yeah, it's not the easiest thig to work with. Use a development system with a package manager and use the package manager.

Comment: Hi, could you point to me a good development system with package manager to use boost ? I am on macOS, new to c++ so not sure what to use. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly I don't know Mac worth beans, but I'd look at [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Could be as simple as `brew install boost`, but would work with a `brew` installed toolchain and probably not with the built-in tools.

Answer (score 1):

The error function is implemented in the C++ standard library as `std::erf` in `<cmath>`. However, the inverse error function, which is essentially what you want here, is not implemented in the standard library.

You need to use some third-party library that implements it. Whether that is boost or any other one of course doesn't matter.

There are also going to be general statistics libraries that implement the distribution functions directly for different distributions.

That is no different than in Python. `scipy.stats.norm.ppf` is also not part of the Python standard library that comes with a Python installation. It is part of the SciPy library.

However, generally the C++ standard library is much narrower in scope than the Python one.

(Alternatively you can of course implement the function yourself.)

Recommendations for specific libraries are off-topic here.